# how can I add records to the zone file without restarting the named service?

Tags: linux, dns, bind

I'm working on centos6.5 and bind9 and I have managed to add records to a DNS zone by doing this steps:

creating the key:

`dnssec-keygen -a HMAC-MD5 -b 128 -n HOST example.com.`

editing conf. file:

```
// TSIG Key
key "example.com." {
 algorithm hmac-md5;
 secret "THE KEY GENERATED ABOVE";
}; 

zone "example.com" IN {
 type master;
 file "example.com.zone";
 allow-update{ key "example.com."; };
};
```

give the named authorization to the /var/named folder:

```
# chown -R named:named /var/named
# find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;
# find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
```

I have adding records using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Defining Variables
DNS_SERVER="localhost"
DNS_ZONE="example.com."
USER_NAME="dd2.example.com."
IP="192.168.1.7"
TTL="60"
RECORD=" $USER_NAME $TTL A $IP"
echo "
server $DNS_SERVER
zone $DNS_ZONE
debug
update add $RECORD
show
send" | nsupdate -k Kexample.com.+157+55566.key
```

it didn't return any error.

I test if I add this record by using dig command:

```
#dig +short dd2.example.com.
192.168.1.7
```

but the problem that the record added doesn't appear in the zone file 'example.com.zone':

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 86400  ; 1 day
example.com     IN SOA  dns.exaple.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
        2001062504 ; serial
        21600      ; refresh (6 hours)
        3600       ; retry (1 hour)
        604800     ; expire (1 week)
        86400      ; minimum (1 day)
        )
    NS  dns.example.com.
    A   192.168.1.2
    MX  10 mail.example.com.
$ORIGIN example.com.
$TTL 86400  ; 1 day
ex1         A   192.168.1.2
ex2         A   192.168.1.2
ex3         A   192.168.1.3
ex4         A   192.168.1.4
```

but when I restart the named service: `service named restart` the record appears in the zone file:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 86400  ; 1 day
example.com     IN SOA  dns.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
        2001062504 ; serial
        21600      ; refresh (6 hours)
        3600       ; retry (1 hour)
        604800     ; expire (1 week)
        86400      ; minimum (1 day)
        )
    NS  dns.example.com.
    A   192.168.1.2
    MX  10 mail.example.com.
 $ORIGIN example.com.
 $TTL 60 ; 1 minute
 dd2         A   192.168.1.7
 $TTL 86400  ; 1 day
 ex1         A   192.168.1.2
 ex2         A   192.168.1.2
 ex3         A   192.168.1.3
 ex4         A   192.168.1.4
```

my question is :

Is it a way to the record to be added to the zone file without restarting the named service?

NOTE: rndc reload MYZONE or rndc reload didn't work

this what happend when I use reload

`[root@dd Shells]# rndc reload example.com.
 rndc: 'reload' failed: dynamic zone`

Comment: Dynamic zones have a journal file that goes along with them.  Look for a file like example.com.zone.jnl.  It's a binary file so you won't be able to view it directly, but recent dynamic update changes are stored in this file, and then periodically written back into the example.com.zone file.  You can use `rndc sync` to force this action to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer:

my problem was that BIND can't `rndc reload zone` with the dynamic zones so BIND won’t allow us to reload a dynamic zone. So we have to tell bind to temporarily stop allowing dynamic updates. This is handled with the freeze option.

```
rndc freeze example.com
```

then reloading

```
rndc reload example.com
```

then allowing dynamic updates again:

```
rndc thaw example.com
```

Comment: Also, when you gracefully stop DNS, the journal files all get reconciled into the main zone file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `/etc/init.d/named reload`?

Also, why `rndc reload <namezone>` didnt work? Did you get an error?
Try changing your "serial" to current date and version and rerun `rndc reload`.

You can also try `rndc flush` before reloading the zone.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is my serial `2001062503` how can I change it to the current date, and what the last two numbers representing assume that `2001` is the year and `06` is the month and `25` is the day what `03` is for?? @Deeh

Comment: This action won't work, dynamic zones can't be "reload"ed.  You have to freeze, make changes, then thaw.

Comment: @Networker, dynamic zones automatically increment serial numbers as the content is updated, monotonically increasing.  Setting it to the date will work once, but it won't stay that way.